# useState() function not updating values and useEffect() alternative not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, synchronization

I'm having a problem with the **useState** hook, which is whenever I call the **setSate**, it doesn't change the value of the **state**. This porblem I'm getting it in a custom **SearchBar** I created, where, whenever the user introduces something the **SearchBar** will give him some suggestions, like a normal **SearchBar**, this is done by calling a function that will call the **miniSearch** search engine to search through the data(called 'FruitsAndVeggies.js) and save it in the state **suggestions**, these suggestions will be shown in a list in the screen. The problem is that the list is not shown, because the **suggestions** state is empty, I checked it with console.log() and it doesn't seem to update. Could someone help me fix this solution?

Btw, I created a scratch **SearchBar** in the **ProfileScreen** component and it works perfectly, but on the other one it doesn't.

Here's the **SearchBar** that gives me that problem:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import MiniSearch from "minisearch";
import { ScaledSheet, verticalScale, scale } from "react-native-size-matters";

/**
 * Generic SearchBar Component.
 *
 * A reusable and customizable search bar component with suggestions for React Native applications.
 *
 * @component
 * @param {boolean} [border=false] - Determines whether to show a border around the search bar.
 * @param {StyleSheet.NamedStyles} [addStyles] - Additional styles for the search bar.
 * @param {string} [placeholder="Search"] - Placeholder text displayed in the search bar.
 * @param {Function} [handleOnFocus] - Function to call when the search bar gains focus.
 * @param {Function} [onChangeText] - Function to call when the text in the search bar changes.
 * @param {Array} [data] - An array of suggestion items to display.
 * @param {Function} [onSuggestionPress] - Function to call when a suggestion item is pressed.
 * @param {Function} [keyExtractor] - Function to extract a unique key for each suggestion item. Default is 'id'
 * @returns {React.Element} Generic SearchBar component.
 */

export default function SearchBar({
  border = false,
  addStyles,
  placeholder = "Search",
  handleOnFocus,
  onChangeText,
  data,
  onSuggestionPress,
  keyExtractor = (item) => item.id,
}) {
  const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(false);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  // MiniSearch engine for data
  const miniSearch = new MiniSearch({
    fields: ["name"],
    idField: "id",
    storeFields: ["name"],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      miniSearch.addAll(data, ["name"]);
      console.log("SearchBar -> Data added");
    }
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (suggestions)
      console.log("Search suggestions: " + JSON.stringify(suggestions) + "\n");
  }, [suggestions]);

  /**
   * Handles the change in the search bar text.
   *
   * @param {string} newText - The updated text in the search bar.
   */
  const handleChangeText = async (text) => {
    //checking if text is empty
    if (!text) {
      setShowSuggestions(false);
      setSuggestions([]);
      return;
    }
    let suggestion = miniSearch.autoSuggest(text);
    if (suggestion) {
      setSuggestions(suggestion);
      setShowSuggestions(true);
      console.log(
        "SearchBar -> suggestions: " + JSON.stringify(suggestions) + "\n"
      );
    }
    if (onChangeText) onChangeText(text);
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.searchbarView,
        border && styles.searchBarBorder,
        addStyles,
      ]}
    >
      <TextInput
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          fontSize: 16,
        }}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChangeText={handleChangeText}
        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
        blurOnSubmit={true}
      />
      {showSuggestions && suggestions && (
        <FlatList
          data={suggestions}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.suggestionItem}>
              <Text onPress={() => onSuggestionPress(item)}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  searchbarView: {
    height: verticalScale(35),
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: verticalScale(30),
    paddingHorizontal: scale(10),
    marginHorizontal: scale(20),
  },
  searchBarBorder: {
    borderColor: "#1ACE2B",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: scale(7),
  },
  suggestionItem: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#e0e0e0",
    padding: verticalScale(10),
  },
});
```

here's where I call it:

```
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import SliderComponent from "../Components/SliderComponents";
import ProductComponent from "../Components/ProductHorizontalComp";
import Stores from "../Data/Stores";
import FruitsAndVeggies from "../Data/FruitsAndVeggies";
import Akcijos from "../Data/Akcijos";
import SearchBar from "../Components/Generic/SearchBar";

/**
 *
 * @returns Component with the main page where all the stores and the basic prodcuts are shown
 */
export default function StoreScreen({ navigation }) {
  /**
   * Header that shows the title on the left and a Button on the right
   * @param {string} titleText What will be shown on the title
   * @param {Function} handleOnPress Function that will be called when pressed on the Button
   * @param {string} buttonTitle Title of the
   * @returns
   */
  const viewAllHeader = (titleText, handleOnPress, buttonTitle = "ViewAll") => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          paddingTop: 20,
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: "700",
          }}
        >
          {titleText}
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, color: "#00da34" }}
          onPress={handleOnPress}
        >
          {buttonTitle}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const consl = () => console.log("Focused");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SearchBar
        border={true}
        handleOnFocus={consl}
        onChangeText={(text) => console.log(text)}
        data={FruitsAndVeggies}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
      />
      {/* Horizontal SrollView */}
      <ScrollView>
        {/* Horizontal scrollView of all the stores */}
        {viewAllHeader("Stores", () =>
          navigation.navigate("ViewAll", {
            array: Stores,
            title: "Stores",
            type: 0,
          })
        )}
        <ScrollView
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {Stores.map((store) => (
            <SliderComponent
              key={store.id} // Make sure to provide a unique key for each SliderComponent
              name={store.name}
              image={store.Logo}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>

        {/* Fruits and veggies */}
        {viewAllHeader("Fruits and Veggies", () =>
          navigation.navigate("ViewAll", {
            array: FruitsAndVeggies,
            title: "Fruits and vegetables",
            type: 1,
          })
        )}

        <ScrollView
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {FruitsAndVeggies.map((item) => (
            <ProductComponent
              image={item.image}
              store={item.store}
              name={item.name}
              quantity={item.quantity}
              quantityType={item.quantityType}
              price={item.price}
              isCardDiscounted={item.isCardDiscounted}
              discountPrice={item.discountPrice}
              navigation={navigation}
              soldBy={item.soldBy}
              key={item.id}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>

        {/* Actual discounts */}

        {viewAllHeader("Other discounts", () =>
          navigation.navigate("ViewAll", {
            array: FruitsAndVeggies,
            title: "Fruits and vegetables",
            type: 1,
          })
        )}

        {/* Discount Posts */}
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          style={{ marginTop: 10, paddingRight: 20 }}
        >
          {Akcijos.map((item) => (
            <ProductComponent
              key={item.id}
              navigation={navigation}
              image={item.image}
              store={item.store}
              name={item.name}
              quantity={item.quantity}
              price={item.price}
              discountPrice={item.discountPrice}
              isCardDiscounted={item.isCardDiscounted}
              soldBy={item.soldBy}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

here's the **scratch SearchBar** that works fine:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import MiniSearch from "minisearch";
import FruitsAndVeggies from "../Data/FruitsAndVeggies";
import genericStyles from "../Styles/genericStyles";

export function ProfileScreen() {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState([]);

  const searchEngine = new MiniSearch({
    fields: ["name"],
    idField: "id",
    storeFields: ["name"],
  });

  searchEngine.addAll(FruitsAndVeggies, ["name"]);

  const onChangeText = (text) => {
    if (!text) {
      setSuggestions(false);
      setSearchResults([]);
      return;
    }
    let suggestions = searchEngine.autoSuggest(text);
    if (suggestions) {
      setSuggestions(suggestions);
      setShowSuggestions(true);
      console.log("Search suggestions: " + JSON.stringify(suggestions) + "\n");
    }
    // let searchResults = searchEngine.search(text);
    // if (searchResults) setSearchResults(searchResults);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, ...genericStyles.genericCenteredAlignment }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          marginTop: "50%",
          width: "80%",
          height: 50,
          ...genericStyles.genericBorder,
        }}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        onBlur={() => setShowSuggestions(false)}
      />
      {showSuggestions && suggestions && (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>Suggestions</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={suggestions}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text
                style={{ ...genericStyles.genericBorder, flex: 1 }}
                onPress={() => onSuggestionPress(item)}
              >
                {item.suggestion}
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.suggestion}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      {searchResults && (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList
            data={suggestions}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text
                style={{ ...genericStyles.genericBorder, flex: 1 }}
                onPress={() => onSuggestionPress(item)}
              >
                {item.suggestion}
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.suggestion}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

and here's the data that is searched:

```
const FruitsAndVeggies = [
  {
    name: "Bananai",
    quantity: 1,
    quantityType: 2,
    discountPrice: null,
    isCardDiscounted: false,
    price: 1.19,
    image:
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/lastmile-ui/o/images%2Fchain_products%2FIKI%2Fthumb_iNqZIWhnRVjabieALQrW.jpg?generation=1654518838165052&alt=media",
    soldBy: 2,
    store: 1,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "Batatai",
    quantity: 1,
    quantityType: 2,
    discountPrice: true,
    isCardDiscounted: false,
    price: 1.9,
    soldBy: 2,
    store: 1,
    id: 7,
  },
  {
    name: "Citrinos",
    quantity: 1,
    quantityType: 2,
    discountPrice: 1.69,
    isCardDiscounted: false,
    price: 2.49,
    image:
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/lastmile-ui/o/images%2Fproducts%2Fthumb_H83PY5twSuOZBcPevKFy.jpg?generation=1631695789675754&alt=media",
    soldBy: 2,
    store: 1,
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "Mandarinai",
    quantity: 1,
    quantityType: 2,
    discountPrice: 1.49,
    isCardDiscounted: true,
    price: 2.99,
    image:
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/lastmile-ui/o/images%2Fproducts%2Fthumb_Hy7HIb8PQCGqEvATZw8b.jpg?generation=1631695783290806&alt=media",
    soldBy: 2,
    store: 1,
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    name: "Avokadai",
    quantity: 1,
    quantityType: 5,
    discountPrice: null,
    isCardDiscounted: false,
    price: 0.69,
    image:
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/lastmile-ui/o/import%2Fphotos%2Fconverted%2Fproduct%2Fglobal_1RA2MejrFpM61j0dpP43_cTAkEjfDTeMFXf0e6W4JKKhwXXA3_cIQ08jOtIths09SLOkmW_thumb.jpg?generation=1665477260007150&alt=media",
    soldBy: 5,
    store: 1,
    id: 4,
  },
  {
    name: "Sveriami obuoliai ŠAMPION",
    quantity: 1,
    quantityType: 2,
    discountPrice: 0.69,
    isCardDiscounted: false,
    price: 0.99,
    image:
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/lastmile-ui/o/images%2Fproducts%2Fthumb_hEyrjLkWqfDN7Ce8b3K5.jpg?generation=1589636330241009&alt=media",
    soldBy: 2,
    store: 1,
    id: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "Besėklės žaliosios vynuogės",
    quantity: 500,
    quantityType: 1,
    discountPrice: 1.49,
    isCardDiscounted: false,
    price: 2.49,
    image:
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/lastmile-ui/o/images%2Fchain_products%2FIKI%2Fthumb_hcmNGxBKsp0jcdhciqfK.jpg?generation=1654374772066054&alt=media",
    soldBy: 5,
    store: 1,
    id: 6,
  },
];

export default FruitsAndVeggies;
```

As you can see I've tried the **useEffect()** hook and it doesn't work.

Is there any solution where the **setState** can update its' value instantly?

Thanks for your help :) !!

Comment: I'm not seeing you setting the `miniSearch` values in your first example as the one you did in the second with `searchEngine.addAll(FruitsAndVeggies, ["name"]);`. Also, the console.log() after the setState call will not work all the time since the setState function is an asynchronous operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: I tried all the answers shown, but none work :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good idea to call all that logic inside the onChangeText from the TextInput component. It would be a good idea to make that function to only have one responsibility, and that would be to set the state that will store the text inserted by the user. One other thing about that method, everytime the user types a character or erases it, it will make a request to the miniSearch engine, imagine how many calls that would be, it will decrease the app's performance and can mess up the data between render and update cycles.

If I would code something like that, I would make the function onChangeText responsible only for setting a state that would store the text typed. After that, I would have a debounce call for the miniSearch engine, doing that, the miniSearch engine would only be called after a desired delay. I was able to do what you intended, I hope it helps. I know its ReactJS example, but if you swap  input for TextInput and span for Text, it should work just fine.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MiniSearch from "minisearch";
import { documents } from "./documents";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  let miniSearch = new MiniSearch({
    fields: ["title", "text"],
    storeFields: ["title", "category"],
  });

  miniSearch.addAll(documents);

  const onChangeText = (event: any) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      let suggestions = miniSearch.autoSuggest(inputValue);
      setSuggestions(suggestions);
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <>
      {suggestions.map((current) => (
        <span key={current.score}>{current.suggestion}</span>
      ))}

      <br></br>
      <input placeholder="Type here" onChange={onChangeText} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nothing changes immediately, there are many render and update cycles between every life cycle method. Sometimes we mess up the data between renders.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, is this the only solution?. Is there any altenative without a timewout?

Comment: @AissaRouk you dont have to use the timeout, this is just to not overload your application and make it perform better.